# Views date field does not follow custom date format

Tags: 7, views, entities, datetime

I have a custom date format defined (via code), and this is what I see in the administration pages:

[Custom Date Formats (png screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olsLq.png)

In views, I've attached a field, and trying to use a formatter, but they're all showing up like this:

[Views Date Format (png screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZs0.png)

I can't seem to select my m/d/y feature, and even the default (short, medium and long) are strange. I have tried clearing caches, and the usual. The view is being exported with a feature, and I have not tried recreating it, yet. Any ideas?

Here's the code generating the custom date format:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_date_formats().
 */
function custom_date_formats()
{
  $formats = array();

  $formats[] = array(
      'type' => 'm_d_y',
      'format' => 'm/d/Y',
      'locales' => array(),
  );

  return $formats;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_date_format_types().
 */
function custom_date_format_types()
{
  return array(
      'm_d_y' => t('m/d/Y'),
  );  
}
```

Comment: if you try to disable/remove your custom date format, the default Drupal format (short, medium and long) will still show incorrect format "like what you have in the second screenshot"?

Comment: My custom date format is defined programmatically, so I can't disable it via the UI. It does work on another environment though.

Comment: can you post your custom date format code?!

Comment: See the original post for the code.

Comment: once I applied your code the first time, I got the same results as yours in the views, then I added a custom date format with the same format from the UI and then tried views again; it seems to work the right way (as expected) i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I still did not find the answer to this problem, but fixed it. I fixed it by simply saving the custom date format form in Date & Time in Drupal. Simply submitting that form, without making any changes, refreshed the Drupal views, and it started working properly.

I will look into the submit handler to see what caused the problem, and post if I find anything.

Comment: did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: No, I never found out what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to manually do what you did AND ALSO manually set a variable using `variable_set()`.

For example, if (as in your example) your date format's "type" is "m_d_y" and the format is "m/d/Y" then you'd need to do:

```
variable_set('date_format_m_d_y', 'm/d/Y');
```

After that, the Views should start working, and no manual work is required like saving a form.

That said, this doesn't seem ideal, and I'm wondering if I'm just missing a hook or something, but at least it works and it can be automated.